# Inverse of a matrix with exactly two 1s in each column and row

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse

Consider regular binary matrices. When each column and row contains exactly two 1s, it seems that the entries of the inverse are either $0$ or $\pm1/2$.

Example:
$$
A=\begin{pmatrix}1&1&0\\1&0&1\\0&1&1\end{pmatrix},
A^{-1} = \frac{1}{2}\begin{pmatrix}1&1&-1\\1&-1&1\\-1&1&1\end{pmatrix}
$$

Is this observation correct? And how can I prove it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Here is a sketch of proof. For each positive integer $k>2$, let
$$
C_k=\pmatrix{0&&&1\\ 1&\ddots\\ &\ddots&\ddots\\ &&1&0}\in M_k(\mathbb R).
$$
Now call your matrix $A$. It can be shown that, if $A$ is invertible, then
$$
A=P\pmatrix{I_{k_1}+C_{k_1}\\ &I_{k_2}+C_{k_2}\\ &&\ddots\\ &&&I_{k_m}+C_{k_m}}Q
$$
for some permutation matrices $P,Q$ and for some integers $k_1,k_2,\ldots,k_m\ge2$. Note that each $k_i$ must be odd, otherwise $(I_{k_i}+C_{k_i})x=0$ for $x=(1,-1,1,-1,\ldots,1,-1)^T$. However, when $k_i$ is odd, since the $k_i$-th power of $C_{k_i}$ is the identity matrix, we have
$$
\frac12\left(I_{k_i}-C_{k_i}+C_{k_i}^2-C_{k_i}^3+\cdots+C_{k_i}^{k_i-1}\right)(I_{k_i}+C_{k_i})
=\frac12\left(I_{k_i}+C_{k_i}^{k_i}\right)=I_{k_i}.
$$
Therefore all nonzero elements of $(I_{k_i}+C_{k_i})^{-1}=\frac12\left(I_{k_i}-C_{k_i}+C_{k_i}^2-C_{k_i}^3+\cdots+C_{k_i}^{k_i-1}\right)$ are equal to $\pm\frac12$ and likewise for $A^{-1}$.